# SQL How do I update a Column in a table, from a column from another table, only if the data in another column has the same value as another column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Hello This is my question,

SQL How do I update a Column in a table, from a column from another table, only if the data in another column has the same value as another column.

In SQL:

Table 1:

| Part NO | Description | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A30134 | Straight Part Eq | Used for Equipment |
| AS3043 | 3/4 Hedge | Used for Temp |
| AS3021 | 1/3 Hedge | Used for In House |
| AS3011 | 1/4 Sprocket | Used for House |

Table 2:

| Part NO | Description |
| --- | --- |
| A30134 | Hatchet |
| AS3021 | 1/8 Hedge |

Resultant Table:

| Part NO | Description | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A30134 | Hatchet | Used for Equipment |
| AS3043 | 3/4 Hedge | Used for Temp |
| AS3021 | 1/8 Hedge | Used for In House |
| AS3011 | 1/4 Sprocket | Used for House |

So basically, just taking 2 columns from table 2, and comparing the Part No to the Part No of table 1, and only updating the Description that is in table 1, from the description in table 2, and not changing any other descriptions or Part No's.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just did my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `update` with `join`:

```
update table1 inner join
       table2
       on table1.part_no = table2.partno
    set table1.description = table2.description;
```